# Admin module for content managers

Tags: 7

I am building a drupal website for a customer (=content manager) of mine. Normaly I would just adjust the permissions for the content manager so he can change what he needs to. But it would be much simpeler if I could provide a menu with shortcuts of the actions he needs.

To keep everything clean I would like to use rubik and the admin menu.

Is there a way to hide all the "admin" links for the content manager and add some custom menu links my own ? So I can provide a "custom" content management system for his needs without all the drupal possibilities (which I only need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Quickbar](http://drupal.org/project/quickbar) module.

> This is a simple administration toolbar. It allows you to take any menu and assign it to a role. This menu will be displayed at the top of your page as an administration toolbar.

Most of this module is taken from [the] [Admin](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin) [m]odule version 1.x. It also uses some features from the [Toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/toolbar) module.

Answer (score 1):

The links to actions the user doesn't have access to won't appear if I'm not mistaken.

However, you might be better off using the toolbar instead of admin_menu and adding a couple links to management menu.

Try and login as that user, you will see a much less-cluttered toolbar because of permissions :)